# Php check if 5 variables are the same value

Tags: php

In php I need to check if 5 variables are the same value, and then proceed.

Instead of doing

```
if($a == 'logged' && $b == 'logged' && $c == 'logged' && $d == 'logged' && $e == 'logged') 
{ 
   // Code to run here
}
```

Is there a different way to do it? Like:

```
if($a,$b,$c,$d == 'logged')
```

Something like that possible..?

Comment: not sure but could $a == $b == $c == $d == $e == 'logged' this work

Comment: @kpp: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL)`

Comment: I wonder why it does not work?

Comment: @kpp before writing it as a comment, you could [test it yourself](https://eval.in/144484) and see...

Comment: `if (($a == $b) == ($c == "logged")) {
    echo "yup";
}` this worked for me

Comment: @Norman: Can you tell us any details why do you need it?

Comment: You clearly dont know how long it takes for my xampp server to start up. :P

Comment: @kpp somehow you missed this: https://eval.in

Answer (score 9):

You can use something like this

```
$values = array($a, $b, $c, $d, 'logged');

if(count(array_unique($values)) === 1) {
    //All elements are the same
}
```

Comment: This is elegant, but much less efficient and hard to read / understand / debug. But a really interesting idea!

Comment: @arkascha this could be wrapped into helper function with proper name, so the coder will know what it's doing :)

Comment: @RoyalBg Yep, that is true indeed. But: that makes this even less efficient, besides having to create an array on-the-fly then also a function call has to be done.

Comment: @arkascha not true at all: `function compareValues($value) {
 return count(array_unique(func_get_args()))==1;
}` so you can pass `$a = 'asd';
$b = 'asd';
$c = 'asd';
var_dump(compareValues('asd', $a, $b, $c));`

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your point here. That version is different from your answer above, but is has similar problems. Just that now you don't create an array and call a function, now you call _four_ functions, _which is even less efficient_! Function calls are _really_ expensive.

Comment: @arkascha what do you mean as two functions? There is only one user defined function which is called `compareValues()` which accepts one MUST HAVE param - the value to compare with, i.e. `logged` and limitless other parameters which it will compare to $value i.e. will check if func_get_args() are all equal

Comment: so If one needs to check 5 values compared to `logged`, he just needs: `if(compareValues('logged', $a, $b, $c, $d, $e) { ... }`

Comment: Yep, and the evaluation of that has to make four function calls. I mean it is not as if a function call comes for free once code has been moved into a function... I suggest you give both approaches a try and time the execution. Best if you try both attempts in a loop of maybe 1000 iterations to get meaningful measurement output less influenced by script compilation.

Comment: @arkascha I can be pretty sure that this evaluation, even if you compare 100 variables to `logged` will not have visible slow down of the page. It will still load for very few milliseconds

Comment: @RoyalBg Sorry, but you are in absolutely no position to make _any_ judgement about how long some unknown page takes to load. You are _guessing_. Let's stop this, it is _not_ constructive.

Comment: @arkascha okay, let me say it another way. If a page loads for 0.1 milliseconds or for 20 seconds, this function, used with 100 variables, will not visibly add additional slow down to the current load time. It could be benchmarked

Comment: Oh, and a side note: that function name is misleading. It should be something like "all_values_equal" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend *against* trying to shorten that. There is no more compact notation available to my knowledge apart from optical effects, none that the php parser accepts. The efficiency would not be better, since internally the same comparisons have to be done anyway.

Instead I usually try to enhance the *readability* of the code instead and use reversed notation, since human time is *much* more expensive than computer power these days :-)

```
if (   'logged' == $a 
    && 'logged' == $b
    && 'logged' == $c 
    && 'logged' == $d 
    && 'logged' == $e )  { 
  // Code
}
```

Comment: Although this might be good advice, it's really not an answer of the question, so it should not be posted as an answer